# How i select anchor tag for adding "active" class when i clicked in jquery?

Tags: jquery

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <h3 class="text-white bg-primary text-center">Notice Board</h3>
                    <div class="list-group" id="b">
                        <a href="" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action " id="a">Cras justo odio</a>
                        <a href="" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" id="a">Dapibus ac facilisis in</a>
                        <a href="" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">Morbi leo risus</a>
                        <a href="" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">Porta ac consectetur ac</a>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

How i selected anchor tag in jquery? Please help me.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [JQuery Selectors documentation](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).

```
$('a').addClass('classname'); // add class to all anchor tags
```

Answer (score 0):

use `event.preventDefault()` to revent the default behaviour of the anchor tag, then you should remove the `active` class added to each `a` tag and then add the class to clicked item by selecting it with `$(this)` selector. Checkout the snippet i have made a working example.

If you dont want to remove `active` class, remove this line of code `$('.list-group a').removeClass('active');`

```js
$('a').on('click',function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  $('.list-group a').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active')
})
```

```css
.active{
 color:red;
 font-size:30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <h3 class="text-white bg-primary text-center">Notice Board</h3>
                    <div class="list-group" id="b">
                        <a href="" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action " id="a">Cras justo odio</a>
                        <a href="" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" id="a">Dapibus ac facilisis in</a>
                        <a href="" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">Morbi leo risus</a>
                        <a href="" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">Porta ac consectetur ac</a>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```